# Keep form values when redirect back in Laravel 4

Tags: forms, redirect, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm trying to keep the values of a form when Redirect::back on Laravel 4, but I can't find a way to do this.

This is my form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'generate', 'files' => true)) }}

    {{ Form::radio('myType', '1', true); }}
    {{ Form::label('myType', '1'); }}

    {{ Form::radio('myType', '2'); }}
    {{ Form::label('myType', '2'); }}

    {{ Form::radio('myType', '3'); }}
    {{ Form::label('myType', '3'); }}

    {{ Form::text('myName'); }}

    {{ Form::file('uploadImage'); }}

    {{ Form::submit('Go'); }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

And my controller:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array('uploadImage' => 'required|image', 'myName' => 'required'));

if ($validator->fails()){
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
}
```

I tryed something like:

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->with('nameValue', Input::get('myName'));
```

And then in the view:

```
    {{ Form::text('myName', $nameValue); }}
```

But it still doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ($validator->fails()){
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
}
```

change to,

```
if ($validator->fails()){
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

you can retreive the value by `Input::old()` method.

[**read more**](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests)

**you tried:** `return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->with('nameValue', Input::get('myName'));`

above, you can get the value from `Session`.

`Session::get('nameValue')`

Answer (score 1):

Hey If you are using laravel 5.2 or greater version than you dont need to write

```
Redirect::back()
```

You can simply use `back()` helper function to do this.

so you can replace your code with below code.

```
if ($validator->fails()){
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

Here is a link for [back() helper function documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-back).