# how to remain value that has been input after redirect back

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, if-statement

so I have an if-else function where it will check what is supposed to be in a form, so when I submit the form the function in the controller does the if-else function. So its something like, if there is no value in a hidden input field then it will redirect the user back to the form, but when it does that, all the values for the other text input go missing and a user has to key in all over again. I don't want that to happen. Instead, I want all the other text input to remain. How can I do that?

my blade:

```html
        <form id="form-project" role="form" autocomplete="off" action="{{action('Web\TravelController@store')}}" method="POST">
          {{csrf_field()}}
          <div class="card-bg">
            <div class="back-btn">
              <a href="{{action('Web\TravelController@index')}}">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Back</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                    <a type="button" class="btn tab-btn active btn-tab-lg">Book a trip</a>
                    <a type="button" class="btn tab-btn btn-tab-lg" href="{{action('Web\TravelController@multiCity')}}">Multi-city</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="add-space"></div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                    <label class="btn tab-btn btn-tab-lg">
                      <input type="radio" name="is_return_trip" class="is_return_trip" value="0" onchange="hideReturn(this)">One-way
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn tab-btn active btn-tab-lg">
                      <input type="radio" name="is_return_trip" class="is_return_trip" value="1" checked onchange="hideReturn(this)">Return
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="extra-padding">
                @if(request()->user()->hasRole('PA'))
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Request as</label>
                      <select class="form-control border-input" name="user_id" required>
                        <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
                        @foreach($user->bosses as $boss)
                        <option value="{{$boss->id}}">{{$boss->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
                      <input type="hidden" name="pa_id" value="{{$user->id}}">
                      <input type="hidden" name="submitted_by_pa">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                @else
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$user->id}}">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                @endif
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Mode of Transport</label>
                      <select name="travel_data[transport_type_id]" class="form-control getForm select2" required>
                        <option value="">Select a transport type</option>
                          @foreach($transports as $transport)
                          <option value="{{$transport->id}}">{{$transport->name}}</option>
                          @endforeach
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div id="test">
                        <label>From</label>
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control autocomplete border-input inputDatabaseName" placeholder="From" name="travel_data[from]" required>
                          <input type="hidden" class="field administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true" name="travel_data[from_state]">
                          <input type="hidden" class="field country" disabled="true" name="travel_data[from_country]">
                      </div>  
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div id="test2">  
                        <label>To</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control autocomplete border-input inputDatabaseName2" placeholder="To" name="travel_data[to]" required>
                          <input type="hidden" class="field administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true" name="travel_data[to_state]">
                          <input type="hidden" class="field country" disabled="true" name="travel_data[to_country]">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Departure Date</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker departure-date" placeholder="Departure date" name="travel_data[departure_date]" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6" id="return">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Return Date</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker return-date" placeholder="Return date" name="travel_data[return_date]">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="button-toggle">
                      <label>Selected Dates</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <label class="btn tab-btn active btn-tab-lg" >
                        <input type="radio" name="travel_data[is_official_date]" class="is_official_date" value="1" checked  onchange="showOfficialDates(this)">Official
                      </label>
                      <label class="btn tab-btn btn-tab-lg" >
                        <input type="radio" name="travel_data[is_official_date]" class="is_official_date" value="0"  onchange="showOfficialDates(this)">Non-Official
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="officialdDates" style="display: none;">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 add-date">
                    <button class="btn alt-btn-black btn-xs alt-btn dateButton"  type="button">
                      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                      <label>From</label>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="From" class="form-control datepicker fromOfficialDate" name="fromOfficialDate[]">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                      <label>To</label>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="To" class="form-control datepicker toOfficialDate" name="toOfficialDate[]" >
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rulesFormClone"></div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="button-toggle">
                      <label>Accommodation</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <label class="btn tab-btn active btn-tab-lg" >
                        <input type="radio" name="travel_data[accommodation]" class="accommodation" value="1" checked>Yes
                      </label>
                      <label class="btn tab-btn btn-tab-lg" >
                        <input type="radio" name="travel_data[accommodation]" class="accommodation" value="0">No
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">


                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Travel Description</label>
                      <textarea maxlength="500" contentEditable="true" rows="10" cols="50" name="travel_data[description]" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Travel description" required></textarea>
                      {{-- <input name="travel_data[description]" type="text" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Travel Description" required> --}}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Travel Preferences</label>
                      <input name="travel_data[travel_preferences]" type="text" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Travel preferences" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Add Passengers</label>
                      <input name="travel_data[add_passengers]" type="text" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Add passengers">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="pull-right" >
            <button class="submit-btn" name="status" value='S'>SAVE</button>
            <button class="submit-btn text-gold" name="status" value='SB'>SUBMIT</button>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </form>
        <div class="row" style="display: none;">
          <div class="row datesForm">
            <div class="col-lg-12 add-date">
              <button class="btn alt-btn-black btn-xs alt-btn dateButton"  type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                <label>From</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="From" class="form-control datepicker fromOfficialDate" name="fromOfficialDate[]">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                <label>To</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="To" class="form-control datepicker toOfficialDate" name="toOfficialDate[]" >
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card-bg summary-side-bar">
          <h4 class="title">Summary</h4>
            <h5>Travel Type</h5>
            <p class="traveltype">Return</p>
            <h5>Travel Route</h5>
            <p class="DatabaseName"></p>
            <h5>Departure Date</h5>
            <p class="departure-date1"></p>
            <h5>Return Date</h5>
            <p class="return-date1"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and my function is:

```js
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $user = Auth::user();
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        $inputs = $request->all();
        $inputTravel_data = $request->input('travel_data');
        if($request->has('is_return_trip'))
        {
            $travelTitle = $inputTravel_data['from'].' - '.$inputTravel_data['to'];
            $multiCity = 0;
            $is_return_trip = $inputs['is_return_trip'];
        }else{
            $count = count($inputs['travelLeg']);
            $title = $inputTravel_data['from'][0];
            for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) 
            {
                $title .= ' - ' . $inputTravel_data['from'][$i];
            }
            $travelTitle = $title. ' - ' .$inputTravel_data['to'][$count-1];
            $multiCity = 1;
            $is_return_trip = 0;
        }
        if(!$inputTravel_data['from_country']){
            return redirect()->back();
        }else{
            if(array_key_exists('id', $inputs) && $inputs['id'])
            {
                $travel = Travel::where('id',$this->decode($inputs['id']))->first();

                if(!$travel)
                    return $this->error('message','No travel found for this user');

                $travel->update([
                    'status' => $inputs['status'],
                    'title' => $travelTitle,
                    'is_multicity' => $multiCity,
                    'is_return_trip' =>  $is_return_trip,
                    'company_id' => $user->company_id,
                    'submitted_by_pa' => $inputs['user_id'] != Auth::user()->id ? 0 : 1,
                    'pa_id' => $inputs['user_id'] != Auth::user()->id  ? $inputs['pa_id'] : null,
                    ]);
                if($inputs['status'] == 'SB' && $inputs['user_id'] == Auth::user()->id){
                    foreach($travel->travel_data()->where('removed',0)->get() as $t) {
                        $t->update(['removed'=> 1]);
                    }
                }elseif($inputs['status'] == 'S'){
                    foreach($travel->travel_data()->where('removed',0)->get() as $t) {
                        $t->delete();
                    }
                }

                if($request->has('is_return_trip'))
                {
                    $travelLeg = new TravelLeg;
                    $travelLeg->travel_id = $travel->id;
                    $travelLeg->transport_type_id = $inputTravel_data['transport_type_id'];
                    $travelLeg->accommodation =  $inputTravel_data['accommodation'];
                    $travelLeg->travel_region_id =  $inputTravel_data['travel_region_id'];
                    $travelLeg->travel_purpose = TravelPurpose::find($inputTravel_data['travel_purpose_id'])->name;
                    $travelLeg->description = $inputTravel_data['description'];
                    $travelLeg->travel_prefernces = $inputTravel_data['travel_preferences'];
                    $travelLeg->add_passengers =  $inputTravel_data['add_passengers'];
                    $travelLeg->from = $inputTravel_data['from'];
                    $travelLeg->from_state = $inputTravel_data['from_state'] ?? '';
                    $travelLeg->from_country = $inputTravel_data['from_country']  ?? '';
                    $travelLeg->to = $inputTravel_data['to'];
                    $travelLeg->to_state = $inputTravel_data['to_state']  ?? '';
                    $travelLeg->to_country = $inputTravel_data['to_country']  ?? '';
                    $travelLeg->departure_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $inputTravel_data['departure_date'])));
                    if (!empty($inputTravel_data['return_date']))
                    {
                        $travelLeg->return_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $inputTravel_data['return_date'])));
                    }
                    $travelLeg->title = 'Travel Leg 1';
                    $travelLeg->is_official_date = $inputTravel_data['is_official_date'];
                    $travelLeg->mode_of_transport = TransportType::find($inputTravel_data['transport_type_id'])->name;
                    $travelLeg->region = TravelRegion::find($inputTravel_data['travel_region_id'])->name;
                    $travelLeg->travel_purpose_id = $inputTravel_data['travel_purpose_id'];
                    $travelLeg->processed = 0;
                    $travelLeg->save();
                    if ($travelLeg->is_official_date == self::IS_OFFICIALDATE)
                    {
                        $travelLeg->official_date()->delete();
                    }
                    if ($travelLeg->is_official_date == self::IS_NOT_OFFICIALDATE)
                    {
                        $travelLeg->official_date()->delete();
                        for ($i = 0; $i < count($inputs['fromOfficialDate']); $i++)
                        {

                            $travelDate = new TravelDate;
                            $travelDate->travel_leg_id =  $travelLeg->id;
                            $travelDate->from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $inputs['fromOfficialDate'][$i])));
                            $travelDate->to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $inputs['toOfficialDate'][$i])));
                            $travelDate->save();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
                    {
                        $travelDataFromState ='';
                        $temporaryIndex = $i;
                        if ($inputTravel_data['from_state'][$temporaryIndex] == '') {
                            if (($temporaryIndex-1) <= 0) {
                                $temporaryIndex = 0;
                            } else {
                                $temporaryIndex = $temporaryIndex - 1;
                            }
                            $travelDataFromState = $inputTravel_data['to_state'][$temporaryIndex];
                        } else {
                            $travelDataFromState = $inputTravel_data['from_state'][$temporaryIndex] ?? '';
                        }
                        $travelDataFromCountry = '';
                        if ($inputTravel_data['from_country'][$temporaryIndex] == '') {
                            if (($temporaryIndex-1) <= 0) {
                                $temporaryIndex = 0;
                            } else {
                                $temporaryIndex = $temporaryIndex - 1;
                            }
                            $travelDataFromCountry = $inputTravel_data['to_country'][$temporaryIndex];
                        } else {
                            $travelDataFromCountry = $inputTravel_data['from_country'][$temporaryIndex] ?? '';
                        }

                        $travelLeg = new TravelLeg;
                        $travelLeg->travel_id = $travel->id;
                        $travelLeg->transport_type_id = $inputTravel_data['transport_type_id'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->accommodation =  $inputTravel_data['accommodation'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->travel_region_id =  $inputTravel_data['travel_region_id'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->travel_purpose = TravelPurpose::find($inputTravel_data['travel_purpose_id'][$i])->name;
                        $travelLeg->description = $inputTravel_data['description'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->travel_prefernces = $inputTravel_data['travel_preferences'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->add_passengers =  $inputTravel_data['add_passengers'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->from = $inputTravel_data['from'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->from_state = $travelDataFromState;
                        $travelLeg->from_country = $travelDataFromCountry;
                        $travelLeg->to = $inputTravel_data['to'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->to_state = $inputTravel_data['to_state'][$i]  ?? '';
                        $travelLeg->to_country = $inputTravel_data['to_country'][$i]  ?? '';
                        $travelLeg->departure_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $inputTravel_data['departure_date'][$i])));
                        $travelLeg->title = 'Travel Leg ' . $inputs['travelLeg'][$i+1];
                        $travelLeg->is_official_date = $inputTravel_data['is_official_date'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->mode_of_transport = TransportType::find($inputTravel_data['transport_type_id'][$i])->name;
                        $travelLeg->region = TravelRegion::find($inputTravel_data['travel_region_id'][$i])->name;
                        $travelLeg->travel_purpose_id = $inputTravel_data['travel_purpose_id'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->processed = 0;
                        $travelLeg->save();

                        if ($travelLeg->is_official_date == self::IS_OFFICIALDATE)
                        {
                            $travelLeg->official_date()->delete();
                        }
                        if ($travelLeg->is_official_date == self::IS_NOT_OFFICIALDATE)
                        {
                            $travelLeg->official_date()->delete();
                            $dates = $inputs['OfficialDate'][$inputs['travelLeg'][$i+1]];
                            for ($j = 0; $j < count($dates['from']); $j++)
                            {
                                $fromODate = new TravelDate;
                                $fromODate->travel_leg_id =  $travelLeg->id;
                                $fromODate->from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $dates['from'][$j])));
                                $fromODate->to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $dates['to'][$j])));
                                $fromODate->save();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if($user->id != $inputs['user_id']){
                    $user = User::find($inputs['user_id']);
                }
                $travel = $user->travels()->create([
                    'status' => $inputs['status'],
                    'title' => $travelTitle,
                    'is_multicity' => $multiCity,
                    'is_return_trip' => $is_return_trip,
                    'company_id' => $user->company_id,
                    'submitted_by_pa' => $inputs['user_id'] != Auth::user()->id ? 0 : 1,
                    'pa_id' => $inputs['user_id'] != Auth::user()->id  ? $inputs['pa_id'] : null,
                    ]);

                $this->generateRef($travel);

                if($request->has('is_return_trip'))
                {
                    $travelLeg = new TravelLeg;
                    $travelLeg->travel_id = $travel->id;
                    $travelLeg->transport_type_id = $inputTravel_data['transport_type_id'];
                    $travelLeg->accommodation =  $inputTravel_data['accommodation'];
                    $travelLeg->travel_region_id =  $inputTravel_data['travel_region_id'];
                    $travelLeg->travel_purpose = TravelPurpose::find($inputTravel_data['travel_purpose_id'])->name;
                    $travelLeg->description = $inputTravel_data['description'];
                    $travelLeg->travel_prefernces = $inputTravel_data['travel_preferences'];
                    $travelLeg->add_passengers =  $inputTravel_data['add_passengers'];
                    $travelLeg->from = $inputTravel_data['from'];
                    $travelLeg->from_state = $inputTravel_data['from_state'] ?? '';
                    $travelLeg->from_country = $inputTravel_data['from_country'] ?? '';
                    $travelLeg->to = $inputTravel_data['to'];
                    $travelLeg->to_state = $inputTravel_data['to_state'] ?? '';
                    $travelLeg->to_country = $inputTravel_data['to_country'] ?? '';

                    $travelLeg->departure_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $inputTravel_data['departure_date'])));
                    if (!empty($inputTravel_data['return_date']))
                    {
                        $travelLeg->return_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $inputTravel_data['return_date'])));
                    }
                    $travelLeg->title = 'Travel Leg 1';
                    $travelLeg->is_official_date = $inputTravel_data['is_official_date'];
                    $travelLeg->mode_of_transport = TransportType::find($inputTravel_data['transport_type_id'])->name;
                    $travelLeg->region = TravelRegion::find($inputTravel_data['travel_region_id'])->name;
                    $travelLeg->travel_purpose_id = $inputTravel_data['travel_purpose_id'];
                    $travelLeg->processed = 0;
                    $travelLeg->save();

                    if ($travelLeg->is_official_date == self::IS_NOT_OFFICIALDATE)
                    {
                        for ($i = 0; $i < count($inputs['fromOfficialDate']); $i++)
                        {

                            $travelDate = new TravelDate;
                            $travelDate->travel_leg_id =  $travelLeg->id;
                            $travelDate->from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $inputs['fromOfficialDate'][$i])));
                            $travelDate->to =date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $inputs['toOfficialDate'][$i])));
                            $travelDate->save();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
                    {
                        $travelDataFromState ='';
                        $temporaryIndex = $i;
                        if ($inputTravel_data['from_state'][$temporaryIndex] == '') {
                            if (($temporaryIndex-1) <= 0) {
                                $temporaryIndex = 0;
                            } else {
                                $temporaryIndex = $temporaryIndex - 1;
                            }
                            $travelDataFromState = $inputTravel_data['to_state'][$temporaryIndex];
                        } else {
                            $travelDataFromState = $inputTravel_data['from_state'][$temporaryIndex] ?? '';
                        }
                        $travelDataFromCountry = '';
                        if ($inputTravel_data['from_country'][$temporaryIndex] == '') {
                            if (($temporaryIndex-1) <= 0) {
                                $temporaryIndex = 0;
                            } else {
                                $temporaryIndex = $temporaryIndex - 1;
                            }
                            $travelDataFromCountry = $inputTravel_data['to_country'][$temporaryIndex];
                        } else {
                            $travelDataFromCountry = $inputTravel_data['from_country'][$temporaryIndex] ?? '';
                        }

                        $travelLeg = new TravelLeg;
                        $travelLeg->travel_id = $travel->id;
                        $travelLeg->transport_type_id = $inputTravel_data['transport_type_id'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->accommodation =  $inputTravel_data['accommodation'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->travel_region_id =  $inputTravel_data['travel_region_id'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->travel_purpose = TravelPurpose::find($inputTravel_data['travel_purpose_id'][$i])->name;
                        $travelLeg->description = $inputTravel_data['description'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->travel_prefernces = $inputTravel_data['travel_preferences'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->add_passengers =  $inputTravel_data['add_passengers'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->from = $inputTravel_data['from'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->from_state = $travelDataFromState;
                        $travelLeg->from_country = $travelDataFromCountry;
                        $travelLeg->to = $inputTravel_data['to'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->to_state = $inputTravel_data['to_state'][$i] ?? '';
                        $travelLeg->to_country = $inputTravel_data['to_country'][$i] ?? ''; 
                        $travelLeg->departure_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(   str_replace('/', '-', $inputTravel_data['departure_date'][$i])));
                        $travelLeg->title = 'Travel Leg ' . $inputs['travelLeg'][$i+1];
                        $travelLeg->is_official_date = $inputTravel_data['is_official_date'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->mode_of_transport = TransportType::find($inputTravel_data['transport_type_id'][$i])->name;
                        $travelLeg->region = TravelRegion::find($inputTravel_data['travel_region_id'][$i])->name;
                        $travelLeg->travel_purpose_id = $inputTravel_data['travel_purpose_id'][$i];
                        $travelLeg->processed = 0;
                        $travelLeg->save();

                        if ($travelLeg->is_official_date == self::IS_NOT_OFFICIALDATE)
                        {
                            $dates = $inputs['OfficialDate'][$inputs['travelLeg'][$i+1]];
                            for ($j = 0; $j < count($dates['from']); $j++)
                            {
                                $fromODate = new TravelDate;
                                $fromODate->travel_leg_id =  $travelLeg->id;
                                $fromODate->from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $dates['from'][$j])));
                                $fromODate->to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $dates['to'][$j])));
                                $fromODate->save();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if($inputs['status'] == 'SB')
            {
                $pivotT = \DB::table('travel_approver_inboxes')
                        ->where('travel_id', $travel->id)
                        ->where('removed',0)
                        ->get();
                        foreach($pivotT as $p) {
                            $travel->approver()
                            ->newPivotStatement()
                            ->where('id', $p->id)->update(['removed'=> 1]);
                        }
                (new TravelApprover($travel))->assign();
                $travel->update(['submitted_date' => $today,'remark'=> null]);
                $travel->fresh();   
            // (new Notification)->addNotification($travel,'travel');
                // dd($travel->approver->last());
            }
            return redirect(action('Web\TravelController@index'));
        }
    }
```

so as you can the main redirect is here:

```php
if(!$inputTravel_data['from_country']){
    return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: Save `$_POST` in a global variable & set the default values of the input fields from that? First time round, they would be blank, but not after the redirect.

Comment: You can use laravel [old helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-old) as in [example with old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652814/laravel-blade-old-input-or-default-variable).
or send information back: [example with ->with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781617/keep-form-values-when-redirect-back-in-laravel-4)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may wish to redirect the user to their previous location, such as when a submitted form is invalid. You may do so by using the global back helper function. Since this feature utilizes the session, make sure the route calling the back function is using the web middleware group or has all of the session middleware applied:

```
Route::post('user/profile', function () {

    return back()->withInput();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read through the docs, as it is explained clearly and simple over there: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input